# Why count outputs wrong chars from char array

Tags: c++, arrays, cout

I have a multidimensional char array that I write to, then print out using a nested for loop, yet for some reason it outputs rubbish, what have I done wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CheckerBoard {
public:
    void initBoard() {
        for(int y = 0; y < 0; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < 0; x++) {
                if((x % 2) == 0) {
                    _board[y][x] = ' ';
                } else {
                    _board[y][x] = '*';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void printBoard() {
        for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                cout << _board[y][x];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    char _board[8][8];
};

int main() {
    CheckerBoard cb;
    cb.initBoard();
    cb.printBoard();
    return 0;
}
```

I think it's to do with me looping wrong, and it's accessing a value outside of the array, but I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Please include the output (actual and expected) in the actual question. Don't post screenshots of text, especially on external sites where some people can't access them. Also include the *relevant* code in the actual question.

Comment: @orange Regardless of whether the code is there or not, the question is one of the countless debug-this-code-for-me questions posted every day, with little or any additional information such as results of debugging attempts etc. Really not the kind of thing many people, myself included, think SO should be encouraging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initBoard` doesn't do anything.

```
for(int y = 0; y < 0; y++)
```

`y` starts at `0`. `0` is not less than `0`, so the loop does not run.

Put the size of your board (`8`) in a constant, then use that everywhere, and you'll be less likely to use the wrong number.